# Behavior of the null set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to work out problems to understand the null set beyond the notion of, "an empty box". Therefore, I have tried to work out some problems concerning set operations involving the null set. I was wondering, is my logic correct here?

1. $\emptyset$ $\in$ $\emptyset$

This is false because the empty set is defined as having no elements. This can be expressed via contradiction as $if \; empty \; \rightarrow \; no \; elements$, which yields as $T \rightarrow F$, which is false.

2. $\{\{\emptyset\}\} \subseteq \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$

This would be false because the two sets in $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ are $\emptyset$ and $\{\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\\$

3. $\{\emptyset\} \; \cap \{\emptyset,\{\{\emptyset\}\}\} = \emptyset$

This would be true, because the sets of $\{\emptyset,\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ include $\emptyset$ and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, which don't equal $\{\emptyset\}$.

4. $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$

This would be true because the empty set is a subset of all sets.

Comment: 1,2,4 are correct. 3 is wrong. The intersection of two sets is itself a set, and what 3 claims is that set is empty, but in fact the two sets have an element in common.

Comment: Ah, so what would be the set of intersection for #3? {$\emptyset$}?

Comment: Yes. $\emptyset$ is an element of both sets, so the intersection set will contain it as an element. SInce there are no other elements in common, $\{\emptyset\}$ is the intersection. In this case, the first set is a subset of the second, so it is the intersection.

Comment: @HardyBaker For 3, you might find it helpful to reason using $a$ instead of $\emptyset$ for the set elements. It means you don't get confused between "the intersection of two disjoint sets" and "the elements of the sets".

Comment: Patrick, thank you for the recommendation. It makes things a lot of easier to visualize it.